# Implementation of circular queue in visualbasic6

Tags: vb6

```
 Public Function insert(x As Integer)
    If front = 0& & rear = n - 1 Or rear + 1 = front Then
     MsgBox "queue FULL !!!", vbOKOnly, "QUEUE"
    ElseIf front = -1 Then
     front = rear = 0
    ElseIf rear = n - 1 Then
     rear = 0
    Else
     rear = rear + 1
    End If
    arr(rear) = x
    MsgBox x, vbOKOnly, "INSERTED"
    List1.AddItem x
End Function
```

This is insert() of a circular queue . I am getting an error in "If front = 0& & rear = n - 1 Or rear + 1 = front Then"
error is"Runtime error '13' type mismatch".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is also wrong

```
front = rear = 0
```

Should be

```
front = 0 
rear = 0
```

`=` has **two** meanings in VB6

- `=` is the equality operator, same as `==` in a c-like language
- `=` is also the assignment statement, like the `=` operator in a c-like language

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant

```
If front = 0& & rear = n - 1 Or rear + 1 = front Then
```

to be

```
 If front = 0 And rear = n - 1 Or rear + 1 = front Then
```

and you probably really meant

```
If (front = 0 And rear = n - 1) Or rear + 1 = front Then
```

and are you mixing your "x" and "n"

Comment: He probably also meant to not use VB6. *Shudder* Oh well, you know what I always say, "With life, as with VB6: on error, resume next."

Comment: yeah problem sloved.... But now am getting an error in "arr(rear)=x" 
error is :"Subscript out of range "

Comment: obviously your array arr is smaller than rear

Comment: but rear has been initialised wid '-1'

Comment: so the length or your array is -1?

Comment: But i have ReDim my array in a function of size 'n' and 'n' will be inputed by the user which is >5

Comment: step through your code and look at the value of rear and look and the len of arr and go from there

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11159/discussion-between-rick-and-gratzy)